# C# Class Library is not automatically updated

Tags: c#, class, dll, reference

I have 2 class libraries (`ClassA` and `ClassB`), which are being referenced by another library (`ClassX`). These libraries are being referenced in a `Web Project` (`Web01`).

Originally, only `ClassA` and `ClassB` are being used in `Web01`. When I used `ClassX` in `Web01`, it automatically modified my references to `ClassA` and `ClassB`. I noticed this because whenever I change `ClassA` or `ClassB`, and build `Web01`, `ClassA.dll` and `ClassB.dll` dates are not updated. They are the same dates as `ClassX.dll`. `ClassA.dll` and `ClassB.dll`'s date will only be updated until I build `ClassX`.

Is there a work around on this such that I don't have to build `ClassX` everytime I do some changes in `ClassA` and `ClassB`?

Comment: are all 4 projects in the same solution, and if so are all the references project references?  If not, this sounds like expected behaviour...

Comment: Visual Studio will only recompile a project if there are changes, so simply compiling the solution will not always result in every project being recompiled needlessly. If all these projects are in the same solution, VS will ensure each is compiled as needed.

Comment: ClassA, ClassB and Web01 are on the same project/solution. When I started ClassX, I also added ClassA and B to its solution. All are project references because I was thinking that whenever I update and rebuild ClassA and ClassB, updates will show in Web01. The problem is I also need to rebuild ClassX. My problem is future development of ClassX will be transerred to others and I cant bother them and ask to rebuilt it unless they have changes.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in a comment above, if the projects reside in the same solution, the builds should be cascading.

If they reside in different solutions, then as far as I know, a custom build script would be needed to make sure all are compiled/recompiled and that the proper build order is followed.

Again, this is only as far as I know. There may be other options.

Something else to note, just in case it applies: If you have constant values in any of the referenced assemblies and a constant gets changed, remember to recompile EVERYTHING that references that assembly, as constants get resolved at compile time and replaced with literal values directly in the binary.